# How to use two types of regex in single regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string field. I need to pass UUID string or digits number to that field.
So I want to validate this passing value using regex.

sample :

```
stringField = "1af6e22e-1d7e-4dab-a31c-38e0b88de807";
stringField = "123654";
```

For UUID I can use,

```
"[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}"
```

For digits I can use

```
"\\d+"
```

Is there any way to use above 2 pattern in single regex

Comment: Why don't you just try and parse with `UUID.fromString()` and if that fails, do `new BigInteger()`? More simple and no need for regexes

Comment: @fge On that note, found [**`this interesting issue`**](http://anuff.com/2011/04/javautiluuidcompareto-considered-harmful/).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that you are seeking to _parse_ UUIDs

Answer (score 3):

Yes..you can use `|`(OR) between those two regex..

```
[\\da-f]{8}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{12}|\\d+
                                                            ^
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. You will need parentheses to make groups. This is just making the last group either a group of 12 alphanumerics or more than one number. I could be completely wrong, though.

Comment: @Ryaminal i guess op only wants to validate the input..he doesn't want groups..op should clarify on this though

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
"(?:[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12})|(?:\\d+)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group regular expressions with () and use | to allow alternatives.

So this will work:

```
(([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12})|(\\d+)
```

Note that I've adjusted your UUID regular expression a little to allow for upper case letters.

Comment: @Ryaminal - just trying to be multiplatform.

Comment: Why all the parens? All that needs capturing is the result. `.group()` will be enough.

Comment: @fge indeed you are correct but I like to keep my regular expressions as portable as possible. Feel free to edit my answer; including an alternative specific to Java.

Comment: I don't see where portability enters into account here? Can you elaborate? All regex engines have the capacity to return the matched text, as far as I know...

Comment: I'm with @fge; I don't know of any regex flavor that requires you to use groups the way you're doing here.

Answer (score 1):

How are you applying the regex?  If you use the `matches()`, all you have to do is OR them together as @Anirudh said:

```
return myString.matches(
    "[\\da-f]{8}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{12}|\\d+");
```

This works because `matches()` acts as if the regex were enclosed in a non-capturing group and anchored at both ends, like so:

```
"^(?:[\\da-f]{8}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{12}|\\d+)$"
```

If you use Matcher's `find()` method, you have to add the group and the anchors yourself.  That's because `find()` returns a positive result if any *substring* of the string matches the regex.  For example, `"xyz123<>&&"` would match because the `"123"` matches the `"\\d+"` in your regex.

But I recommend you add the explicit group and anchors anyway, no matter what method you use.  In fact, you probably want to add the inline modifier for case-insensitivity:

```
"(?i)^(?:[\\da-f]{8}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{12}|\\d+)$"
```

This way, anyone who looks at the regex will be able to tell exactly what it's meant to do.  They won't have to notice that you're using the `matches()` method and remember that `matches()` automatically anchors the match.  (This will be especially helpful for people who learned regexes in a non-Java context.  Almost every other regex flavor in the world uses the `find()` semantics by default, and has no equivalent for Java's `matches()`;  that's what anchors are for.)

---

In case you're wondering, the group is necessary because alternation (the `|` operator) has the lowest precedence of all the regex constructs.  This regex would match a string that *starts* with something that looks like a UUID or *ends* with one or more digits.

```
 "^[\\da-f]{8}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{4}-[\\da-f]{12}|\\d+$"  // WRONG
```

Comment: By forcing the start and end anchors Alan is preventing accidental matches if there are substrings which look like your uuid or digits. e.g. `this is not a valid match-12345678` would return true without the anchors. +1 for well thoughout